# Button draws normal state after pressing

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and just starting the very basics. I implement my custom button skin using .9.png images for norma/focus/pressed states. It works fine, but I noticed that after a pressed the focussed button it visually "lost" focus and draws the normal state frame. I planned to use different state images to highloght what button is selected right now, but it seems that it would not work. I noticed also that the same happens with the default LAF button. Is it OK, or it's just emulator issue? What the good workaroud can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the following may help. I wanted to have one of the buttons in a list of button to be coloured differently, to highlight the fact you were already in that section.

My buttons android:background field was set to the following drawable (drawable/my_btn.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_focused" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

You'll noticed i've got an item with the android:state_selected="true" attribute set.

Then in code you can have

```
Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_btn_1);
mybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nav_secondary_1);
        btn.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if you can set the selected stat of a Button through a property in the xml. Not sure you would want to.

The order of the item's are also important as it can change the visibility of the other states. The current order will allow you to see the pressed and focused states. however, if you moved the selected item to the top you would find that your pressed and focused states would not be displayed.

I am not sure if you can combine the pressed, focused and selected states to allow for more customised graphics. I haven't tried it but the following would allow for more complicated state based graphical layouts.

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected_focused" />
```

Read up on Selectors here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: i'm not advocating this as correct expected user experience/behaviour, but rather it is possible to provide a selected state for a Button.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior in touch mode, and you should not seek to tamper with it. This is how your users will expect for your app to behave. If you set the focus without touching the screen, such as when using the trackball that's available on most devices, it will indeed remain in focus, but in touch mode there's no visual representation for the state of having focus.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, David!
But does it means the only way to "highlight" selected button is by doing it programatically?

Comment: I mean, if I have a menu at the botom part of the scren that allows me to start some activities I want thwe button still remains in "selected" mode indicating that this activity is "connected" with this button, something like toggle button...

Thanks

Comment: @Rilakkuma: You could consider doing your own graphic not for the `Button`, but for the `ToggleButton` which is designed exactly for this: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html